# Not receiving push notification from FCM to iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building an iOS app with FCM push notifications. I followed the Google Firebase docs and other tutorials, but my AppDelegate never execute the function didReceiveRemoteNotification, so when I send notification from my Firebase Console it does nothing.

I have this, for now:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()            
        FIRApp.configure()
        connectToFcm()

        return true
    }

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
    print("<-TOKEN->")
    print(token)
}

func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)
}
```

- I also installed Firebase on my CocoaPods file.
- I registered the App in the Firebase Console with the same Build ID.
- I have "Required Background Modes -> App downloads content in response
  to push notifications" in my info.plist file
- I've created and uploaded my APNS Certificate to my settings in Firebase Console.

And when I start the App, it builds succesfully, and prints my this on console:

```
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
2017-05-29 12:10:56.101 incidenciasSifu[1811] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
Optional(Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=2001 "FIRMessaging is already connected" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=FIRMessaging is already connected})
<-TOKEN->
Optional("03545fbbb986e2ffdfa50ac9e3eb6fe07e6fe4694cdfd000d673a0bf5ea53f6a")
Connected to FCM.
```

I'm newbie on Swift, and I don't know if I forgot to add some code in AppDelegate or something.

Help please! I spent too much hour on this :(

Answer (score 1):

Before registering for push notifications you need to ask user's to grant you necessary privileges.
Try this code in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
} else {
    let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

Also it would be useful to check the reason of app start. Add the following code in this method:

```
if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] {
    self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: remoteNotification as! [AnyHashable : Any])
}
```

Additionally you may add didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError method to understand the reason of possible error:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print ("Eror: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Ok, I did this, except add remoteNotification, on which function I have to add it?

Comment: First two pieces should replace your call of application.registerForRemoteNotifications() in didFinishLaunching

Answer (score 0):

You need to register  notification in appdelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            //  actions based on whether notifications were authorized or not
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }
```

Comment: I already had application.registerForRemoteNotifications() but not center.requestAuthorization, is it necessary?